# How do I specify the rows that have additional pieces while using separate() in R?

Tags: r, tidyr

I'm using tidyr to clean up my data like this

```
df <- data.frame(Time = c("2014-01-03", "2014-01-04-morning", "01-06", "2014-01-07"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

str(df)
'data.frame':   4 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ Time: chr  "2014-01-03" "2015-01-04-morning" "01-06" "2014-01-07"
```

Then when I using

```
separate(df, Time, c("Y", "M", "D"), sep = '-')
     Y  M    D
1 2014 01   03
2 2014 01   04
3   01 06 <NA>
4 2014 01   07
```

Warning messages:
1: Expected 3 pieces. Additional pieces discarded in 1 rows [2]. 
2: Expected 3 pieces. Missing pieces filled with `NA` in 1 rows [3].

Then how could I get the list that indicates the rows having additional pieces, in this example,  [2]?

Comment: You can't have a `Date` class with format `"2014-01-04-A"` or `"01-06"`

Comment: I'm just demonstrating some dirty data

Comment: If you can update with your expected output, it would be great.

Comment: I have no problem in output, instead, I want to get a list that indicate those rows has additional pieces, like "2014-01-04-morning"

Comment: Do you need `read.table(text = df$Time, sep="-", header = FALSE, fill = TRUE, colClasses = 'character', stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`

Comment: What about the 3rd element, which is split incorrectly "01-06"

Comment: I can filter out that by `df %>% filter(is.na(D))`

Comment: Ok, then check `df %>%
   mutate(flag = str_count(Time, "\\w+") >3) %>%
   separate(Time, into = c("Y", "M", "D"))`

Comment: If you just want to find which have more elements, then you can use `df$Time[str_count(df$Time, '-') > 2]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An option would be to convert to 'Date' class with `anydate` (from `anytime` - it would convert most of the formats into `Date` class, but there would be some edge cases "01-06" - which is not a Date as it doesn't have the 'Year' or one of the components)

```
library(tidyverse)
library(anytime)
df %>% 
   mutate(DATE = anydate(DATE)) %>% 
   separate(DATE, into = c("Y", "M", "D"))
```

#### Update

If we need a flag column

```
df %>%
   mutate(flag = str_count(Time, "\\w+") >3) %>%
   separate(Time, into = c("Y", "M", "D"))
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(DATE = c("2014-01-03", "2014-01-04-A", "01-06", 
       "2014-01-07"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: But I want to know which specific rows that have such exception problem, and make it to a list. How should I do it?

Comment: @JHow Can you update your post with expected output.  I am confused by what you needed.  A reproducible example `df <- data.frame(DATE = c("2014-01-03", "2014-01-04-A", "01-06", "2014-01-07"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`